# How to download or access ('web3/lib/web3/event.js');

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

The following test script requires('web3/lib/web3/event.js');

```
const SolidityEvent = require('web3/lib/web3/event.js');

function decodeLogs (logs, contract, address) {
 return logs.map(log => {
const event = new SolidityEvent(null, contract.events[log.topics[0]],   address);
return event.decode(log);
});
}

module.exports = {
 decodeLogs,
};
```

Does anyone know where I can find the library or is the library installed with the web3 download ???

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Install `truffle` and use `npm install web3` command to install web3. Refer [this](https://blog.amr-gawish.com/building-a-production-ready-ethereum-dapp-from-idea-to-final-product-first-section-the-3b9975a226c) article for environment setup.

Comment: Thanks, I have the problem sorted now. 

Correction is to use just 'web3' instead of ('web3/lib/web3/event.js')

Answer (score 0):

Answer: to require only web3

```
const SolidityEvent = require('web3');

 function decodeLogs (logs, contract, address) {
 return logs.map(log => {
 const event = new SolidityEvent(null, contract.events[log.topics[0]],      address);
 return event.decode(log);
 });
 }

 module.exports = {
 decodeLogs,
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble into this question this works for 1.0.0 of web3:

```
function decoder(logs, abi) {
  const topics = {};
  const args = abi.filter(x=>x.type === "event").forEach(e=>topics[e.signature]=e);
  
  let results = logs.filter(x=>x.topics.filter(t=>topics[t]).length > 0);
  return results.map(log=>{ return {args:web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(topics[log.topics[0]].inputs, log.data, log.topics), event:topics[log.topics[0]].name}});
}
```